# How can I make it impossible for my class member functions to be called in main?

Tags: c++, class, member, private-members

I'm writing a few classes for a homework assignment and I want it to be impossible for my class member functions to be called in main. If they are, I want the program to exit. How would I know when my member functions are being called? As for the class, each object represents a color in the format of <100,200,215>. Thanks for the help!

```
class Color{

public:
    Color( unsigned red = 0, unsigned green = 0, unsigned blue = 0 );    //  ctor
    unsigned getRed() const;    //  accessor
    unsigned getGreen() const;    //  accessor
    unsigned getBlue() const;    //  accessor
    Color & setRed( unsigned red );    //  mutator
    Color & setGreen( unsigned green );    //  mutator
    Color & setBlue( unsigned blue );    //  mutator
    const Color & output() const;
private:
    unsigned myRed;
    unsigned myGreen;
    unsigned myBlue;
    static unsigned okColor(unsigned color);

}; //Class Color

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

}


Color::Color( unsigned red, unsigned green, unsigned blue):
myRed(okColor(red)),myGreen(okColor(green)),myBlue(okColor(blue))
{
    //initialization list here...
}

//accessors
unsigned Color::getRed() const {return myRed;}
unsigned Color::getGreen() const {return myGreen;}
unsigned Color::getBlue() const {return myBlue;}

//mutators
Color & Color::setRed(unsigned red){
    myRed = okColor(red);
    return *this;
}

Color & Color::setGreen(unsigned green){
    myGreen = okColor(green);
    return *this;
}

Color & Color::setBlue(unsigned blue){
    myBlue = okColor(blue);
    return *this;
}

//output 
const Color & Color::output() const{

    cout << "<" << myRed << "," << myGreen << "," << myBlue << ">" << endl;
    return *this;
}

//checkers
unsigned Color::okColor(unsigned myColor){

    if (myColor > 255) {
        die("Color intensity is out of range!");
    }

    return myColor;
}

bool die(const string & msg){

    cerr << endl << "Fatal error: " << msg <<endl;
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

Color mixture( const Color & color0, const Color & color1, double weight){

    double color1Multiplier = 0;
    Color mixture;
    unsigned mixtureRed;
    unsigned mixtureBlue;
    unsigned mixtureGreen;

    color1Multiplier = 1 - weight;

    mixtureRed = (color0.getRed() * weight) + (color1.getRed() * color1Multiplier);
    mixtureBlue = (color0.getBlue() * weight) + (color1.getBlue() * color1Multiplier);
    mixtureGreen = (color0.getGreen() * weight) + (color1.getGreen() * color1Multiplier);

    mixture.setRed(mixtureRed);
    mixture.setBlue(mixtureBlue);
    mixture.setGreen(mixtureGreen);

    return mixture;
}
```

Comment: But you want to be able to call them from other functions?

Comment: Yes. I just want them to not be able to be called in main.

Comment: One way will be to make them private and then make the functions where you want to access them in `friend`s

Comment: That is if they are not too many. Otherwise it will be ugly. But what exactly is the reason for this?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but you really need to learn how [not to design classes](http://www.idinews.com/quasiClass.pdf).

Comment: This was an assignment in the homework. I didn't understand exactly what it meant.

Comment: If you are trying to hide your stuff from other people. You should make it a **library** and then hide the source deep down the ocean :)

Comment: Just to say, you don't have to show us so much code. The essence of your question would take about 10 lines.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about that. Normally, I get asked to provide more code so I normally just post more than less.

Comment: @user1681673 Have a look at [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), which describes how to get the balance right for how much code to show.

Answer (score 2):

It is simple to prevent your class from being called from main. Don't create the class in `main` - no class -> no way to call the member functions (unless they are static). You can also move your `#include` of the class header to some file that isn't in the same source as `main`.

Unfortunately, there is no (trivial and/or portable) way to determine which function called your code [especially if we bear in mind that modern compilers quite often move code around, so although your code is calling `mixture` from main, the compiler decides to just move that into `main`, because that makes it faster, smaller or whatever other goal the compiler has with inlining functions].

Other that that, there is no way to stop a function from being called from any function that has access to the object. For nearly every aspect of functions, `main` is no different from other functions. The only difference is that `main` is called from the C++ runtime library. But the compiler doesn't really care if your function is called `main`, `kerflunk` or `fred`.

Comment: I'm never going to use `foo` and `bar` anymore. From now on, it's gonna be `kerflunk` and `fred`! ;)

Comment: He isn't trying to stop the functions from being called in `main`... he wants different behavior (exit immediately) if any is.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I think the answer clearly states this is not possible.

Comment: Ok, for this, I don't think that's a viable option. Thank you for the help though. What about if a object is created that is <25,30,50>. Is there a way to stop the program is the setRed function is called in main to change the value?

Comment: I think this is a better way to frame the question.

Comment: @user: Yes, if you know something about your runtime environment.  But I feel like it's a very bad design to try to do so.

Comment: Yeah, a lot of the assignments we're asked to do I feel are bad design as well.

Comment: @user1681673: I think this is a case of [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You need to achieve X, and you *think* the way to do that is to achieve Y. And then you ask how to achieve Y. Here, it would be important to know what is X for you: what are you really trying to achieve? What's bad if the function is going to be called from `main()`, while it is OK if the function will be called from `bar()` and `main()` will call `bar()`?

Comment: P.S.: Of course I meant `kerflunk()`, forget about `bar()` :)

Comment: @user1681673: is it really part of your assignment to make the function behave differently if it's called from `main`. That seems VERY strange as a requirement. I've been programming for 30+ years, and not yet had any requirement to figure out "which function called this code" (except for crash-dumps and call-stacks in debuggers, but that's a bit special).

Comment: I think I asked the question poorly, because the assignment was written poorly. I just over read it and I think what I'm trying to do is protect an object once it's created. For example, if an object <10,10,10> is created I want to make sure it can never be changed from <10,10,10>. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: @user1681673: Then it should be sufficient to remove the mutator functions `setRed()`, `setGreen()`, and `setBlue()`

Comment: @Andy I would, but they have to be there.

Comment: Or let the `set{Red,Green,Blue}()` functions check if the colour is `-1` or `0`, and if not, don't change it (perhaps call `die`).

Comment: @MatsPetersson I'm not sure exactly what that does if I want to change <10,10,10> to <20,10,10>.

Comment: @user1681673: Why do they have to be there? If you want the object not to be modified by anyone, there's no reason for having them there. Or is there a client that can modify them? If so, you may have to re-read the assignment once more and tell us what is actually requested ;)

Comment: Here's what the assignment says, "In all of your member functions, make sure that there’s no way that the main program can corrupt a class object by calling the member functions. (The programmer writing the main function is drunk, recently divorced, and off his meds, so don’t trust his code.) Your classes should complain and die if a member function is called with args that would put the class object in a corrupt state."

Comment: @user1681673: The important bit seems to be "if a member function is called with args that would put the class object in a corrupt state". This doesn't mean nobody can call your function, nor that `main()` cannot call your function: it means your function should check for the validity of the arguments provided

Comment: @user1681673: I don't think so. I believe "corrupt state" is more like "invalid values for a color". For instance, if your color is encoded as three values ranging from 0 to 255 (this is quite usual), then calling `setRed(1729)` could put the object into a corrupt state. Your function must prevent this from happening - it should make some sanity check on the arguments and do nothing (or terminate the program, or throw an exception, or return `false`) if the arguments are invalid as the representation of a color

Comment: Ok, I guess I misunderstood the question being that it seems impossible to do what I originally asked and I already implemented the value checkers. Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: I completely agree with Andy's interpretation. Checking values is an important thing. Not only do we have drunk, recently divorced and off his meds programmers [including all three at once], but there are also programmers that intentionally TRY to make things go wrong. So checking that you don't get "bad state" is always a good idea. Check everything you can check, at every time it could possibly go wrong. Catching errors "early" is also always a good idea. Rather than accepting a bad value and then much later the output is "wrong".

Answer (score 0):

If you create a global object it will be initialised before `main`, and destroyed after `main` exits.

You can use this fact to set a flag and behave however you wish.

Comment: Well, I presume the OP wants the object to be usable AFTER `main` has been called, just not directlky inside `main`.